# Tink iOS SDK different on my flutter code compared to the sample project

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm trying to integrate Tink iOS SDK into my flutter app. Following online docs (although it's mostly inaccurate) and the sample app they have provided on this: https://github.com/tink-ab/tink-link-ios

I have created a Flutter platform channel integration, and I got some of it working. But I'm not sure why there are certain functions available on their swift code compared to mine. Specifically, on their [sample app](https://github.com/tink-ab/tink-link-ios/tree/master/Samples/TinkLinkSimpleSample), they could call `Tink.Transactions.connectAccountForOneTimeAccess`. However, when I try that on my swift project in flutter, it says that `Type Tink has no member 'Transactions'`.

I've attempted a flutter clean to clean the xcode build, I also cleaned the xcode build by launching xcode -> projects -> clean.

I noticed in their code it's in a ViewController whereas mine is in an AppDelegate. Not sure if that makes a difference. The following is a snippet from their code:

```
import UIKit
import TinkLink

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // This is a simple sample app, demonstrating how easy it can be to integrate Tinks mobile SDK in your app.

    // First, add your client ID. It can be found on console.tink.com in your apps settings.
    let clientID: String = "43a72f7786564bd8ac42720ea53697eb"
    // Then add `tinksdk://example` into the list of redirect URIs under your app's settings in Console.
    let redirectURI: String = "tinksdk://example"
    // And lastly, the market code for the market you want to test, e.g. "GB" for Great Britain, or "SE" for Sweden.
    let market = Market(code: "GB")
    
    // Now you're all set!
    // Hit Run to test your project with Tinks mobile SDK.
    
    @IBAction func onTransactionsOneTimeAccessTap() {
        let configuration = Configuration(clientID: clientID, redirectURI: redirectURI)
        let controller = Tink.Transactions.connectAccountsForOneTimeAccess(configuration: configuration, market: market) { [weak self] result in
            self?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
            switch result {
            case .success(let connection):
                print("TinkLink OneTimeConnection code: \(String(describing: connection.code)), TinkLink OneTimeConnection credentialsID: \(connection.credentialsID)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("TinkLink OneTimeConnection error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        self.present(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And mine is exactly the same, including the `import TinkLink` part. Only difference is mine is in an AppDelegate since I'm integrating their native iOS SDK into my flutter app.

Attempted fixes:

- Run their code on my iPhone simulator, and their code worked.
- Checked Swift Language version
- Run a `flutter clean` and cleaned xcode build from xcode as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!

**Solution:**
When running `pod update`, specify the pod you need updated. E.g. `pod update TinkLink`

I had already attempted `pod update` before, which was why i didn't consider that option when posting this question. However, after looking through my flutter's ios directory, and in Pods/TinkLink, I looked at the README.md and noticed the minimum iOS version is still 11.0 (Based on web documentation of this SDK, it should be 13.0). And it still mentions TinkLinkUI, which is a deprecated library now. So I ran `pod update TinkLink` specifically, and that solved my issue.